# Process XML using XQuery - incorrect output

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0

I have an XML document describing a car mart. The car mart is a collectiion of parkings. In each parking,
there are many cars. Each car belongs to one category - new/used/rent. The document looks like this:

```
<car_mart>
    <parking>
        <cars>
            <car cat="new">
                <licence>1PYV582</licence> 
                <price>1000</price> 
            </car>
            <car cat="new">
                <licence>6GD5489</licence> 
                <price>2200</price> 
            </car>
            <car cat="rent"> 
                <rental>20</rental>     
            </car>
            <car cat="new">
                <licence>5FN1254</licence> 
                <price>1500</price> 
            </car>  
            <car cat="rent"> 
                <rental>25</rental>     
            </car>          
            <car cat="new">
                <licence>6HB4524</licence> 
                <price>5800</price> 
            </car>              
            <car cat="rent"> 
                <rental>10</rental>     
            </car>          
        </cars>
    </parking>

    <parking>
        <cars>
          <car cat="used">
            <licence>8UA1294</licence>
            <price>800</price>
          </car>
        </cars>
    </parking>

    <!--<parking>
        ...
    <parking>-->

    <cat tag="new">
        <cat_name>New</cat_name>
    </cat>
    <cat tag="used">
        <cat_name>Used</cat_name>
    </cat>
    <cat tag="rent">
        <cat_name>Rent</cat_name>
    </cat>
</car_mart>
```

I would like to extract information using XQuery. The result should look like this:

```
<cat id="new" total_cost="10500">
   <cat_name>New</cat_name>
   <car price="1000"/>
   <car price="2200"/>
   <car price="1500"/>
   <car price="5800"/>
</cat>
<cat id="used" total_cost="800">
   <cat_name>Used</cat_name>
   <car price="800"/>
</cat>
<cat id="rent" total_cost="55">
   <cat_name>Rent</cat_name>
</cat>
```

Till now, I came to this piece of XQuery (3.0). The output is obviously not correct.

```
<car_list>{

for $cat in /car_mart/cat

return 
<cat id="{$cat/@tag}" total_cost="{sum(/car_mart/parking/cars/car/cost)}">
{$cat/cat_name}
  {for $car in /car_mart/parking/cars/car
    return
    if($car/[@cat=$cat/@tag]) 
    then <car price="{$car/price}"></car> 
    else ()
  }

</cat>

}</car_list>
```

I see 2 main problems that I do not know how to resolve:

1. in one category, only cars of that category should be listed (now, all of them are)
2. counting total_sum of that category

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your query:

1. You sum over the `cost` of **all** cars in the database, not the ones in each category.
2. There is no element named `cost` in any `car`, only `price` and `rental`.
3. Your syntax for the predicate in `if($car/[@cat=$cat/@tag])` is wrong, the first forward slash `/` should not be there.

The `if` construct can also be replaced by a single predicate. Changing all of this leads to the following query:

```
<car_list>{
  for $cat in /car_mart/cat
  let $cars-in-cat := /car_mart/parking/cars/car[@cat=$cat/@tag]
  return <cat id="{$cat/@tag}" total_cost="{sum($cars-in-cat/(price|rental))}">{
    $cat/cat_name,
    for $car in $cars-in-cat[price]
    return <car price="{$car/price}"></car>
  }</cat>
}</car_list>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. 3rd problem helped (such a little thing and it can change a lot...).